# Unit Testing Suggestions

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I have a moderately to highly complicated application that is backed by a large database of about 50-60 tables. I'm trying to get as much unit test coverage as possible on the code, but I am really struggling with mocking a dataset and some key concepts. I actually have anxiety at the thought of trying to implement full unit test coverage because I'm not sure how to do the following:

1)Test every possible scenario and data combination for each function.  I.E. One of our functions returns a value based upon about 20 inputs with 3 different possible values for each input.  How could one possibly test all of the values for something like that? And if I could test all those combinations, I would have to write the exact same logical code in the test to determine if it should have passed or not (isn't this redundant?).

2) Data and results change with time!  For example, if I run a query for the number of employees who rented a car in the last week, I will always be returning a different result as time moves forward.  How can I write a unit test that knows how many results to expect if the results will vary from one day to the next?

People say that if you are struggling with unit testing that you are doing it wrong, so please enlighten me on how to best handle these situations.

Comment: I appreciate the down vote.  I'd appreciate it more if there were a reason for it.  I'd love to know what the best practices for unit testing variables that change with time and have x^n possible inputs.

Comment: The reason why is that there is not a concrete question. You're basically asking for "unit testing advice" which you can find with a simple google search (though I recommend looking for BDD advice specifically). In other words: what specific problem do you have and what have you tried?

Comment: 1) Test the edge-cases; and hopefully using a testing framework that allows "data driven" tests. 2) Test results should never change with time, only data. Accept a time parameter (just data now) for such tests *and* use DI/IoC for getting time objects so they can be mocked in tests! The test database queried should also be non-changing (for the expected data/results).

Comment: Read point number 1 and point number 2.  Point number 1 is function that takes in an object which has about 20 properties with about 3 possible values for each property.  It then returns TRUE or FALSE if certain conditions are met.  It's actually really simple code, but unit testing it with every combination of those values seems a bit impossible.   Problem number 2 is that I have search functionality that is dependent upon time that needs to be unit tested. This is a bit easier as I could just mock an object that I know will be within the date range I am searching.

Comment: This question would probably be received more favorably if each sub-question was asked separately and presented in a more immediate "my tests are failing/missing cases" scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment above notwithstanding, here are some thoughts:

- In unit tests you test "units". A large part of the finesse in unit testing is determining what exactly a "unit" is. So what are your units? Hint: They almost never include involving the database.
- Determining proper units is what prevents the problem of results and data changing. If a core bit of functionality changes then sure, a unit test needs to be modified or even deleted, but otherwise it should be minimal maintenance.
- Combinations and permutations - Test things that you actually need to test. You can write some helper code for this. However, you don't always *need* to test absolutely everything, test to the point that is useful and no further.
- I find high levels of testing useful, you however might not. Your experience and abilities at unit testing factor into how useful tests might be.

Comment: Thanks.  One of the articles I recently read suggested testing just a few edge cases at first and then if any bugs appear in production to add those back to your unit tests.  I need to have some sort of data to test my methods with, which is why I have test-data.  I'm not unit testing the actual query generation, just that the correct things are being returned by the methods.

Comment: @RaySülzer A database is typically considered an external system and as such not part of the "unit". Typically in this situation you would either pass the data in as a parameter or base the data source on an interface and stub it. 20 parameters into a method is a horrible idea though in part for the very reason you state. There's no way that they control all the same aspects of the calculation. I encourage you to split it up. Joshua Bloch recommends no more than four parameters in a method.

Comment: It's not 20 parameters persay, the method accepts a single object of class "Employee" which has a bunch of properties on it.  This method then calls a bunch of private methods passing in the properties which returns a bool depending on the value. I will unit test the private methods just by passing in the one or two parameters they need and not unit test the public method.

Comment: Yeah, that might be your best option at this point but be aware that this sets off some red flags that your design likely has problems that might become issues later on.

Comment: For that particular method, since it calls a lot of other methods probably dealing with the data, focus 110% on the flow and behavior. I know I would test it by asserting a specific behavior based on some general data (ex; calls method x on time, method y 2 times). And then make sure that the method deals as little as possible with the data itself.